# Tree tk (file explorer)

Tags: python, python-3.x, treeview

i would like to create a file explorer but m having some trouble with the id = tree.insert()

```
def SUBS(path):
    PO   = ""
    parent = tree.parent(XOM)
    while os.path.exists(path+"/"+PO):
          X1   = 0
          List = os.listdir(path+"/"+PO)
          for element in List:
              X1 += 1
              if os.path.isfile(path+"/"+element):
                 tree.insert(XOM,str(X1),text=element)
              if os.path.isdir(path+"/"+element):
                 id = tree.insert(XOM,str(X1),text=element)
                 PO = element
          break
X    = 0
Path = "/"
WinT = Tk()
tree = ttk.Treeview(WinT ,height=15)
tree.pack(expand=YES,fill=BOTH)
tree.heading("#0" ,text="Directory")

PATH = os.listdir(Path)
for element in PATH:
    X  += 1
    PaTh = Path+"/"+element
    if "//" in PaTh:
       PATH = PaTh.replace('//','/')
    if "//" not in PaTh:
       PATH = PaTh
    if "." in element :
       tree.insert('',str(X),text=element)
    if "." not in element:
       XOM = tree.insert('',str(X),text=element)
       SUBS(PATH)
```

so the problem is the function SUBS() the problem s actually coming from the fact that m using id = at the beginning it should only be used through the function SUBS() otherwise id already exist and it can't work ..         i would like to use id = instead of X = in SUBS() but i can't ..

Comment: What isn't working exactly? What is the expected result you wish?

Comment: well i would like a function that would listdir and add the results to each row if it's a dir like : if os.path.isdir () i want all sub files/dir of each row till nothing left to add .                                                                                           so i modified my code but m having some troubles with the :                   while os.path.exists()

Comment: i can only use id = once that my problem so i need a function that would add every sub files/dirs for every sub dir of each initial row ("/" > var)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want is a recursive function, that is a function which calls itself.

```
def SUBS(path, parent):    
    for p in os.listdir(path):
        abspath = os.path.join(path, p)
        parent_element = tree.insert(parent, 'end', text=p, open=True)
        if os.path.isdir(abspath):
            SUBS(abspath, parent_element)


path = "C:/"
WinT = Tk()
tree = ttk.Treeview(WinT ,height=15)
tree.pack(expand=YES,fill=BOTH)
tree.heading("#0" ,text="Directory")
root = tree.insert('', 'end', text=path, open=True)
SUBS(path, root)
WinT.mainloop()
```

It gets all elements in the directory and add it to the tree-widget. If its another directory than the function calls itself, till they are no more directories left.

Comment: ty a lot it's working :) just how can i close each dir , cause everything is open it's bit messy :p shall i use tree.focus() ?

Comment: Glad you like it, remember to mark this answer as correct. If you want closed tree element change the option `open=True` in the `tree.insert()` method to `open=False`